# Is there any badges like envato badges available readymade? Free or commercial?

Tags: icon, looking-for-similar

I really like envato's badges. I would like to implement such badge system in my website.

[image]

Is there any readymade free or commercial badge pack available?
Thanks

Comment: -1 https://www.google.com/search?q=free+icons Some of these are a bit esoteric and likely custom(what's that golden bear claw-looking thing? the moustache?), but otherwise there's really nothing special here. That flag is completely mismatched, and the ribbon doesn't quite fit, either, so overall their badge system is probably cobbled together from several sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at below icon search engine, I think you'll find everything you want:
once type badges, another time avatar, then there you go...
your collection is complete:

http://findicons.com/